# Цвет текста в консоли C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Как изменить цвет выводимой строки/символа в консоли в C#?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; // устанавливаем цвет
Console.WriteLine("...");
Console.ResetColor(); // сбрасываем в стандартный
```